# MicrosoftSQL - SQL Server Authentication login and password = ALWAYS error

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i currently trying the SQL Server Authentication. i follow this website:
https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/silk-test/200/en/silktestworkbench-help-en/SILKTEST-7FFBB86A-CREATINGNEWSQLSERVERADMINUSER-TSK.html
on how to make an SQL Server Account. for example, i went to security folder and make new security or account. my login name is USER and my password is PASSWORD. i edited the Schema and other whatever the website said. regardless, when i try to login and enter my password, it still cause errors that i cannot login

it say:
Cannot connect to DESKTOP-6PK6OTL\SQLEXPRESS
Login failed for user 'USER'.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Is there something i must do before i enter? ive been making 3-5 security/accounts but the problem remains the same.

im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: If you connect with the `LOGIN` that you used to create the new `LOGIN`, and go to the SQL Server logs, you'll be able to find the true authentication error. What was it?

Comment: Did you give it login permission ?

Comment: the Source says "Logon", 
then next to it is the Message: 
"Login failed for user 'USER'. Reason: an attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated Authentication only. [ CLIENT: <local Machine>]"

log type is SQL Server. 
Error type is 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58

Comment: AlwaysLearning - i dont think it has something to do with password. my password is even simple and no capslock...
Ehsan Akbar - i did give it permission on Server Roles as Public and Sysadmin. same goes toUser Mapping and give the Account check to some database. and to the Database role membership, i even give it permission to db_datareader, db_datawriter even db_owner

Comment: "Server is configured for Integrated Authentication only. " tells the exact reason. Configure the server logon to both methods, `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`.

Comment: Serg - thanks for that. so i went to my server. right click it and click properties. then on the left side i went to Security page. then on Server Authentication i check the "SQL Server and Window Authentication mode" but still, even if i tried to restart my MicrsoftSQL, the login error still persist...

Comment: ohh wait. solved it. thanks. yeah i need to click the SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode. then i have to restart it. i mean literally right click on the database engine, click restart and wait for it to restart. idk why but i tried to close the MicrosoftSQL and reopend it. the problem still persist. i guess the best way tor restart it is to literally right click on database engine > restart. thanks to all!

Comment: Restarting SSMS and Restarting the data engine are completely different things, @DreacLeoson . Restarting SSMS when you need to restart SQL Server is like closing and reopening Excel when someone asked you to restart your computer.

Comment: Larnu, i see that explains it. i wished i learn this much earlier. thank you so much! will always keep that in mind.